# multiple a4j:outputpanel are not being rendered in Ajax request in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I have a `drop down list` and on selection of value from dropdown list multiple other elements are rendered. These elements are in separate `a4j:outputpanel`. when i render these elements in Ajax request they are perfectly rendered in Chrome and Mozilla but they are not rendered in IE.

`IE render only one element and not multiple elements`.

how can i render these element in IE ?

i am using a4j:jsfunction for ajax call

`<a4j:jsFunction name="mya4jfunction"
action="#{mybean.myfunction()}"
render="mymage mytextfiled">
</a4j:jsFunction>`

---

`<a4j:outputPanel id="mymage">
<img src="assets/flags/#{myBean.myimage}">
</a4j:outputPanel>`

---

`<a4j:outputPanel id="mytextfiled">
<input id="mytf" name="tf" type="text" value="mybean.mytf" />
</a4j:outputPanel>`

Comment: Not enough information. Show the code. Since a4j:outputPanel generates a plain old `span` that's not the issue.

Comment: @juanignaciosl i have added a code for your clarification

Comment: That code is wrong, AFAIK: a4j:jsFunction doesn't have "render" attribute

Comment: I think it should be reRender, and the ids are comma-separated values, not space-separated

Comment: the code is fine and working perfect in Chrome and Mozilla but not working in IE only. and a4j:jsFunction do have render attribute and no reRender attribute. Only IE has a problem with my code.

Comment: My bad. I'm use RichFaces 3.x, which hasn't. You seem to be using 4.x.